# Add parentheses when using alternative content?

Tags: parentheses

Would you add parentheses in the first place when you write alternative content?

Example:

"This car has a(n) (optional) navigation system."

or

"This car has a (optional) navigation system." ?

Remark: I am not an native English speaker, so please be gentle.

Comment: There really ought to be a word for the **(optional)** placement of of brackets around the word "optional". To me, it's a bit like *tautology*, but with a greater sense of superfluousness.

Comment: And of course if the system is optional, then the car does not actually *have* it. It *might* get one, and only if you *make* it so.

Answer (score -1):

Using parentheses is generally considered bad form or lazy. Usually you'll find that their contents were unnecessary, or could've been more clearly stated with a rewrite. The best way to write the sentence would be like this.

> This car has an optional navigation system.

However, if you are just asking about *how* to use them, then the first sentence is correct, even though it looks strange.

> This car has a(n) (optional) navigation system.

Some stuff on parentheses. http://www.writingsimplified.com/2009/04/how-and-when-to-use-parentheses.html

Comment: I'd much prefer "an" to "a(n)" in the second case. In my mind *a* or *an* is chosen depending on on the sound that immediately follows, not starting sound of the noun it's semantically attached to.